# Mysterious color change of Image when changing minSdkVersion

Tags: android

I've encountered a problem with an image in android. The image hast just some area with a background color and another area which is transparent. I'm using an ImageView to display that image in an activity.
When I compile the app for android:minSdkVersion="3" everything is fine but when I compile the app using android:minSdkVersion="4" the background color changes to a darker color. If I display an image which contains the absolute same background color but no transparent regions the color does not change.

I would appreciate any suggestions why this is happening and what I can do to avoid this color change.

Comment: the same image will also have a darker background color with higher minSdkVersions

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem when changing minSdkVersion from 9 to 16. with api 9 the background was solid black, with api 16 it was a gradient from black to gray.

not sure it solves your problem but i added .Black. to my theme in all my activities in the manifest and then everything was back to normal with a black background:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```